# How to divide exported mysql database file to parts and import to database?

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I have 200 mb exported database file and now I can't import it to hosting database with phpmyadmin because my internet connection is slow. Database from wordpress site. How I can divide  it and import to database?

Comment: Is the database on your local machine and you want to import it on to remote server OR is it the other way around?

Comment: Yes, database in my local server and I must import it on hosting @ksoni

Comment: ok great. Do you have ssh access to the hosting server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to zip the mysql database since it is mostly text, it will reduce the size to almost 10-15% to the original size, so possibly around 20-30 mb.

Please do this on your local machine on your command line.

```
mysqldump -u root -p db | gzip > /tmp/db.sql.gz
```

then copy the db.sql.gz to your remote server using ssh or whatever is available to you and run the below command.

```
zcat db.sql.gz | mysql -u user -p db
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have ssh-access there is no way around splitting your file up, so that phpmyadmin can import it without reaching the max_execution_time.